# How typhoid fever severe case's intestine perforation occur? (non trauma)

Tags: bacteriology, pathology, infectious-diseases, gastroenterology

**In typhoid severe case, intestinal perforation occurs**. As stated [here](https://wjes.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1749-7922-7-4)

> [4, 6]. Intestinal perforation is a serious complication of typhoid fever

**My question here is, how does the bacteria (Salmonella typhi) perforate intestine,like the process?**

*Does the bacteria somehow weakens the walls of intestine and the pressure cause it to rupture?*(Guess)

OR

*Due to the bacteria in the intestine, inflammatory reaction occurs which causes thickening of walls and pressure that leads to rupture?* (Guess)

[Even here, it doesn't state how the perforation occured by the the bacteria](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://pmj.bmj.com/content/postgradmedj/60/706/523.full.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjlh-a89-_yAhUp7nMBHWpTB3AQFnoECBQQAQ&usg=AOvVaw3OwLMgy-YBYSxxrOEAADhy)

Thank you.